# More than one pop up is not coming in IE

Tags: javascript

I have the following html

```
<form action="http://www.test.com" method="post" name="form_test"    target="" >
    <input type="image" src="loader.gif"  id="icon" alt="image" onclick="popup();"/>
</form>

<div id="ij">
ghgfhg
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(){
    window.open ("http://www.google.com","one");
    window.open ("http://www.yahoo.com","two");
}
</script>
```

And when I click the image button I get two pop ups, one for google and one for yahoo in every browser except IE.

In IE, only one popup with 'google', is coming.

And if I allow popup blocker settings in IE brower for the site, where the page is located, then I get two popups.

So let me know what is the reason in IE.

Comment: Are you allowing pop ups for the site in IE, seems like it is keeping you from spamming the user with multiple windows. I see it as a good thing. There is normally a better solution that using pop up windows unless you are spamming users with ads they will never click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup blocker blocks every popup except the first.

http://www.microsoft.com/austria/windowsxp/sp2/sp2_popupblocker.mspx

explains in the last paragraph parts of how it determines whether to block.

Comment: I didn't get a solution for that.But multiple popups are comming in some  sites (in IE), ref http://www.dealbase.com/flight-deals.Please press the 'Check rates' button

Comment: What version are you using? My IE9 on Win7 blocks them all.

Comment: IE8 on WINOWS XP,Iam getting 2 poups and also popup blocker message from browser, because , there is some more popup remaining.So as per your suggestion, there is no way for second popup ,in IE?

Comment: The popup blocker uses some heurestics to decide. I have not found any reference axcept my link in the answer, but here some other rule seems to start working. As I said IE9 blocks them all.